# how to insert wait between block of codes

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2

I want to implement something like this : I am creating snapshots of volume ( using amazon ec2 tools ) and I am storing the details of latest snapshots in a file.

```
#Create snapshots of all attached volumes

echo "Create snapshots of all attached volumes"
read -rsp $'Press enter to continue...\n'
awk '{print $2, $3}' "$EC2_HOME/ActiveVolumes_$today_date" | while read vol_id inst_id; do
    awk '{print $3, $5}' "$EC2_HOME/Instances_$today_date" | while read inst_id2 name; do
        if test "$inst_id" = "$inst_id2"; then
            echo ec2-create-snapshot "$vol_id" -d "$today_date: Daily Backup for $inst_id (VolID:$vol_id InstID:$inst_id)"
             ec2-create-snapshot "$vol_id" -d "$today_date: Daily Backup for $inst_id (VolID:$vol_id InstID:$inst_id)"
        fi
    done
done


#Create a file with all latest snapshots

echo "Create a file with all latest snapshots"
read -rsp $'Press enter to continue...\n'
latestdate=$(ec2-describe-snapshots | grep ^SNAPSHOT | sort -rk 5 | awk '{print substr($5, 1, 10); exit}')
ec2-describe-snapshots | grep "^SNAPSHOT.*$latestdate" > "$EC2_HOME/SnapshotsLatest_$today_date"
```

i want to do one thing. I want to put a wait between two block of codes based on one condition. I want to put a wait after the first block of code is executed. i Want to check if status of is completed then execute next block of code.

```
SNAPSHOT    snap-7749   vol-86d0    pending 2013-12-11T04:17:57+0000    100%    109030037527    35  EBS_Automated_Snapshot_12-10-2013-20:20:13
SNAPSHOT    snap-e2f3dc vol-80  completed   2013-12-11T04:16:49+0000    100%    109030037527    35  EBS_Automated_Snapshot_12-10-2013-20:19:05
```

Comment: Why are you posting the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513092/how-to-insert-a-wait-until-a-specific-condition-is-met-in-linux) again?  Why not edit the earlier one to include more information?

Comment: @devnull: i have deleted the earlier one

Comment: Where is the information you show on pending/completed coming from?  Is it in a file that is updated?  Is it the result of a command that you run?

Comment: when executing the ec2-describe snapshots the result is being written to the file

Comment: Does ec2-create-snapshot return right away and then continue to work in the background, or does it block until it's finished?

Comment: its done now. thanks for your concern :)

Comment: If your problem is solved then delete this question.

Comment: sometimes they block if you delete a question. it has happened with me earlier

Comment: Perhaps when there is already an answer. As this question has no answer, I think it should work.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, why not you submit your own answer, and accept it. At least it can be a reference for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> To check if status of is completed then execute next block of code.

You can also use one of "; && ||" The ; just separates one command from another. The && says only run the following command if the previous was successful" || - if it was not successful. [Examples](https://serverfault.com/questions/373052/is-there-a-difference-between-how-two-ampersands-and-a-semi-colon-operate-in-bas)

If it is not enough there is sleep and wait command:

- Wait: wait, waitpid, waitid - wait for process to change state
- Sleep: delay for a specified amount of time

> To put a wait after the first block of code is executed. Just use sleep num.

```
echo "hello"
# wait 5 seconds
sleep 5 
echo  "Bye"
```

More info: man sleep.